# taskbar application icon is not being updated

Tags: c#, icons, taskbar

I have a problem with `icon` at taskbar.
I have to update my application icon according to performance.
When I am running the program with `.exe` file, during my program runs, icon is being updated automatically at task bar.

However when I publish program, icon is never changing and stays with the icon which I have set before from `properties->application-> icon`.

In addition when application running if I right click the icon at task bar, then click pin this program at taskbar, afterwards again unpin this program at task bar, I do not have same problem.

but I don't want to do every time this process (pin and unpin from taskbar) for my application.
Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any relevant code? Or a way of working you use?

Comment: yes I am changing the icon according to values such as if(ms < 100 ) {this.Icon = Properties.Resources.bad; }  with exe file no problem all icons updating perfectly at taskbar however as i said the problem is after publish, need to do pin and then unpin in order to see updated icons at taskbar.